# Why Can't I Replace Text Within My iframe?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am having trouble trying to replace text within a p tag. I've tried a couple ways to get element by id and replace text but no luck. What am I doing wrong?

**iframe.html**

```
<div>
    <p id="title">Tom Clancy</p>
</div>
```

**Content.js**

```
var iframe  = document.createElement ('iframe');
iframe.src  = chrome.extension.getURL ('iframe.html');
var topview = document.getElementById('sidebar-content');
topview.parentNode.insertBefore(iframe, topview)
```

**What I Have Tried To Change Text:**

```
iframe.getElementById('title').innerHTML = "Harry Potter";
```

and

```
iframe.contentWindow.getElementById('title').innerHTML = "Harry Potter";
```

Comment: Have you tried: iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById('title')?

Comment: I tried it and it seemed to work but it got blocked by this message.

Comment: Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://brickseek.com" from accessing a frame with origin "chrome-extension://dk". The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "chrome-extension". Protocols must match.

Comment: It's a security feature.  If you are using this for testing purposes you can disable this feature on your local browser.  Here's a really good post on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25098153